# Is it possible to track apple wallet pass usage of my application's wallet pass?

Tags: ios, analytics, wallet

I have an app that I have a loyalty card in the app with a simple barcode and I recently added "Add to apple wallet" link and passes to my application.

I couldn't find documentation about a way to track wallet pass usage. Is there any metric I can get from Apple through my app or any way?

Comment: What does usage mean? If the loyalty card is scanned somewhere, you would need the place that scanned it to record that fact.

Comment: I don't have separate barcodes for apple wallet, mobile app and other barcodes. Also I'm curious about tracking options that Apple provides. I also want to see how many times user opens wallet and displays the card regardless of scanning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, Apple does not currently provide usage statistics of the wallet app. You would have to track scans of your QR code yourself.